# How To Disable a Button In Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, disabled-control

I Have A D.G.V And All Of My Column's Type Is DataGridViewButtonColumn , I Want To Disable Some Of That Button's
Like
row[1].cell[1] or somthing else

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == null)
    {
        /// disable that button's
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some more info. Like that button is present in every row? or end of gridview etc.

Comment: in every row this D.G.V made for calendar